# Rerender of pageBlockSection not working on input field change

Tags: visualforce, rerender, actionsupport

I have an input field:

```
<apex:inputField id="tabIndex5" value="{!My_Object__c.Some_Field__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!DoNothing}" rerender="info,subinfo,subinfo2,emailinfo,advancedSettings" />
</apex:inputField>
```

I then add a pageBlockSection

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="advancedSettings" title="{!$Label.advanced_settings}" columns="1" rendered="{!AND(Not(IsBlank(My_Object__c.Some_Field__c)))}">
    <apex:inputField value="{!My_Object__c.Checkbox_Field__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

This correctly renders on page rerender or page load. But if the field is populated and it renders initially, then I clear the field, nothing happens. That pageBlockSection does not go away like it should with its rerender because `Some_Field__c` is now empty. Or if it is empty and then gets populated, the pageBlockSection never shows up. How can I get this onchange to actually rerender the pageBlockSection correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rerender an element with the specific ID if it has `rendered` attribute. Add one more outer `apex:outputPanel` and rerender it instead.

```
<apex:outputPanel id="advancedSettings">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!$Label.advanced_settings}" columns="1" rendered="{!AND(Not(IsBlank(My_Object__c.Some_Field__c)))}">
        <apex:inputField value="{!My_Object__c.Checkbox_Field__c}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:outputPanel>
```